# How to Modify a Parent Component's Data from a Child Component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a Vue.js project and facing a challenge with component communication. I have a parent component defined in App.vue and a child component named SettingsPage.vue. In App.vue, I have a data property "imgSrcProfile" that I need to update from within SettingsPage.vue. I did it with emit but I was curios if there was an easier way.

Settings.vue:

```
<input id="pictureUpload" type="file" accept=".jpg, .png" ref="pictureUpload" v-on:change="$emit('test', $event.target.files[0])">
```

App.vue:

```
//import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import TheWelcome from './components/TheWelcome.vue'
import MainPage from './components/MainPage.vue'
import ProfilePage from './components/ProfilePage.vue'
import FriendsPage from './components/FriendsPage.vue'
import SettingsPage from './components/SettingsPage.vue'
import SignOutPage from './components/SignOutPage.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const currentComponent =  ref ("mainPage")
const showDropDown = ref (false)
const imgSrcProfile = ref ("./src/assets/defaultUserIcon.webp")
const imgSrcLogo = "./src/assets/DailyQuotes_Logo.png"

const components = {
  "mainPage": MainPage,
  "profilePage": ProfilePage,
  "friendsPage": FriendsPage,
  "settingsPage": SettingsPage,
  "signOutPage": SignOutPage
}

function toggleDropDown (){
  showDropDown.value = !showDropDown.value;
}

function onClickChild(value){
  imgSrcProfile.value = URL.createObjectURL(value); 
}

</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
          <img v-on:click="currentComponent='mainPage'" :src="imgSrcLogo">
      </div>
      <div class="profile" >
          <img v-on:click="toggleDropDown" :src="imgSrcProfile">
          <div id="dropDownMenu" v-if="showDropDown">
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'profilePage'">Profile</a>
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'friendsPage'">Friends</a>
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'settingsPage'">Settings</a>
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'signOutPage'">Sign out</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </header>
    <component :is="components[currentComponent]" @test="onClickChild"></component>
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: No there is not a easier way. Parents are meat to send data to children using props and children are meant to send data to parents using emit. There is some syntactic sugar that allows you to use `v-model` instead of specifying an event handler and a prop, but that's it. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html